# Extension API at browsers.* namespace not available in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am building an extension for Chrome based browsers, Firefox and Safari.

I am setting up listeners in the background.js file, and I communicate from the webpage by calling e.g. chrome.runtime.sendMessage method when in chromium based browser. Everything works as excepted and but extension can communicate with the web page.

The issue I am having is when trying to do the same using browser namespace inside of the firefox I get browser is not defined Reference error.

What am I missing? Do you need to update my manifest json to enable browser API?

My manifest json is below

```
{
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "57.0"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/16.png",
      "32": "images/32.png",
      "48": "images/48.png",
      "128": "images/128.png"
    }
  },
    "icons": {
    "16": "images/16.png",
    "32": "images/32.png",
    "48": "images/48.png",
    "128": "images/128.png"
  },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
        "https://*.example.com/*",
         "https://example.com/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tweaked the extension slightly to use a variable API = chrome || browser and then updating my web page to also call method at the respective namespace (chrome.runtime.sendMessage if chrome and browser.runtime.sendMessage if firefox).

Comment: Firefox doesn't support externally_connectable. Use a separate content script and CustomEvent messaging between your page and the script. The script will be able to use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to pass this value further into the extension.